# Dropdown Hover State to stay active while hovering over child (text)

Tags: css, hover, dropdown

I am trying to keep the hover CSS state of my text button to stay while I move my cursor to the child items within the dropdown but can't seem to find the correct solution?

Everything works great except the parent item changes back to the normal state when I move my cursor down onto the child items.

CSS

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #585a5c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-family:engravers;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #585a5c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-family:timesitalic;
  font-size:15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Gallery Of Images
    <!--<span class="caret"></span>--></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="gallery/1.html">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery/2.html">TWO</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2m0hxnkn/. Are you including jQuery and the Bootstrap javascript file? Or are you referring to the background color turning dark blue when it should be white?

Comment: Everything looks fine here, the li itens ( child element) keept the style.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is included.
I am trying to keep the font-family and size the same when hovering over the child elements <li>.

Comment: Here is a link to my project: http://brandonbenscoter.com/LAI/

I am trying to keep the 'Gallery of Images' parent button italicized when hovering over the child item below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change your selectors for the hover event. If I correctly understand what you want to do, you need to change this:

```
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #585a5c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-family:timesitalic;
  font-size:15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

to this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #585a5c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-family:timesitalic;
  font-size:15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

The problem you're having is that you're only applying the above set of styles to the `.btn-primary` element when you are hovering over that particular element. This means that as soon as you take your cursor off the main nav item and onto the nav menu below, `.btn-primary:hover` is no longer true and the styling above stops taking effect.

To remedy this the simple solution is to specify the hover event on the whole dropdown, i.e. the parent `.dropdown` element that also includes `.dropdown-menu`. Using the hover event on this element instead means that when you switch from hovering over `.btn-primary` to hovering over the `.dropdown-menu` nav below it, `.dropdown:hover` is still true because you are still hovering over a child element of `.dropdown`.

All that then remains is to ensure your styling affects the right element, hence the targeting of `.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary` after the hover selector.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much, I had a hunch I was overthinking this and should have tried less instead of more.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, it's something I've had to do before and something like the above is usually the simplest and most elegant solution. Glad it's what you wanted :)